# In unity how i can i save a position of the object and make it return to that position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a script that saves a moving object's position when a certain amount of time passes and then when i press a button i want that object to return to that saved position, but i don't have any idea on how to save the position of the object. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: what i really want to do is i want the object return to where it was 3 seconds ago when i press a button.

Comment: You could store that object in a static class?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the main challenge is that you do not want only one single position stored but rather a continuous storage of the positions up to 3 seconds ago.

So as I see it this means you would need to keep track of all frames positions within the last 3 seconds.

Not sure about performance - there might be way better solutions - but the most straight forward I came up with for now would be using a [`Queue<Vector3>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1) (= first-in fist-out) and a simple initial delay of 3 seconds

The idea here is:

- You have a `Queue<Vector3>` (= first-in / first-out) for the past frames positions
- Each frame in `Update` you add the current `transform.position` to the end of the queue
- You have an initial delay of 3 seconds - during this period you simply pile up positions into the `Queue`
- Once this initial delay has passed, once a frame you pull out the first stored position (from 3 seconds ago) of the `Queue` and assign it to a field `currentResetPostion`
- => When you press your key the position from 3 seconds ago is always available in `currentResetPostion`. Then you reset and restart the position tracking

This could look somewhat like e.g.

```
[Header("Settings")]
[SerializeField] private float timeToTrackBack = 3f;
[SerializeField] private KeyCode keyToPressForReset = KeyCode.Space;

// keeps track of all frames positions
private readonly Queue<Vector3> previousPositions = new();

// The current valid position to reset to when pressing the button
private Vector3 currentResetPostion;

// Timer field for the initial delay
private float delayTimer;

// doing this in OnEnable so you could even decide to disable and enable this component rather then tracking always
private void OnEnable()
{
    RestartTracking();
}

private void Update()
{
    // was space pressed this frame? 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        ResetPosition();
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise pile up positions to be handled later on
        TrackPosition();

        // and handle the next position from the queue
        HandleQueueDelayed();
    }
}

private void HandleQueueDelayed()
{
    // reduce the timer by the time passed since last frame
    delayTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

    // Only once the timer reached 0 we start to pull out the first stored position
    // (from 3 seconds ago) once a frame
    if (delayTimer <= 0 && previousPositions.Count > 0)
    {
        currentResetPostion = previousPositions.Dequeue();
    }
}

private void TrackPosition()
{
    previousPositions.Enqueue(transform.position);
}

private void ResetPosition()
{
    // reset position
    transform.position = currentResetPostion;

    // and restart the tracking
    RestartTracking();
}

private void RestartTracking()
{
    // forget any remaining positions since we want to start a new fresh tracking
    previousPositions.Clear();

    // store the current positions as the reset fallback for the next 3 seconds
    currentResetPostion = transform.position;

    // restart the timer
    delayTimer = timeToTrackBack;
}
```

You might of course want to extend this e.g. including the rotation or in case you are using a `Rigidbody` you would rather want to shift this into `FixedUpdate` and only go through `Rigidbody.position` and additionally reset the `Rigidbody.velocity` etc